# upload a file to localhost using http post?

Tags: java, http, post

I did research and I cant find a good tutorial to post a file with http. Do I have to do a servlet to make the http post or can it be done just with java?

Comment: To handle HTTP post on server you need a servlet, you could make a request from simple java using HttpUrlConnection

Comment: Thanks @JigarJoshi. I just want to upload the files to a localhost, then download the files from the same localhost. I want to measure the time it takes to read/write. I will research about HttpUrlConnection :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011132/multipart-http-request/11011268#11011268

Comment: check my answer on above link. it may help u

Answer (score 2):

to make http post no need of servlet, you can do it using HttpClient library

check

[How to upload a file using Java HttpClient library working with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067655/how-to-upload-a-file-using-java-httpclient-library-working-with-php-strange-pr)

you definitively need a servlet to handle a post request in server side

Answer (score 1):

You can use the FileUpload library from Apache: http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/

A good tutorial to start is this http://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/tutoriales/tutoriales.php?pagina=fileupload

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Apache Commons FileUpload library. That should help you with handling the file upload and storing the file, so you can write less code :)

[Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/)

Answer (score 1):

A client can probably perform the post of the file, however you won't be able to test it without some server application waiting for it.  You can make it in a servlet or use something like WampServer if you know php, the important thing is for something to be listening for your post.

Answer (score 1):

You need two pieces of software: a HTTP client and a HTTP server. You may use Java to implement both, but, depending on your operating system, it may be easier to use PHP on the server side. I wrote [a blog post](http://zybnet.com/java-http-client-and-post-requests/) some time ago to POST data to a PHP script which may be useful. It show how to send a file and arbitrary data at a time: the key is `multipart/form-data` as the MIME type of the request. It also demonstrates how to send data so on the PHP side it's arranged like an array.